# Why is Mozilla Firefox throwing a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, firefox

I'm running a CentOS VM on my windows host machine. The CentOS VM is hosting a local Apache server and for some odd reason the Firefox within the VM is throwing a syntax error to this piece of code here

> ```
> getInput: function() {
>     for (let i in s) {
>       s[i].on("click", function() {
>         console.log($(this).val());
>       });
>     }
> },
> ```

and is saying

> SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer

However, google chrome on the VM is fine. And even chrome/firefox on the host machine are fine.. no errors whatsoever.

Comment: have you compared the versions of the host vs. vm FF instances?

Comment: @the8472, the versions are exactly the same. I access the apache server on my host, so it should be the same version.

Comment: I asked about the FF version, not the JS served.

Comment: @the8472 oh sorry, firefox on VM is 38.3.0. Firefox help says that if there's an update, upon opening the about page it'll automatically update.. so I figure that 38 is the latest linux version. However, my windows version is at 48.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> firefox on VM is 38.3.0

`let` was made available to web content [in FF 44](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/44#JavaScript)

> so I figure that 38 is the latest linux version.

no, that's not the latest version of firefox. but if you're using your distro's package manager instead of installing official firefox builds then the update mechanism probably does not work.

Comment: Even if the update mechanism works, CentOS shares upstreams with Redhat. Redhat's official repositories are ridiculously out of date for almost any package one might be interested in installing anyway.